# Android Native Developmenet : Could not find C compiler

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

I am building an Android App with native support. The app compiles and runs when I'm using a Mac. Now I want to switch to a Windows for development, I get this error when I try to run the app. I'm probably just missing the obvious here, any ideas?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileMyApp_moduleArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibraryMyApp_moduleMainC'.
    No tool chain is available to build for platform 'arm64-v8a':
        - Tool chain 'ndk-gcc' (GNU GCC): Could not find C compiler 'aarch64-linux-android-gcc'. Searched in:
            - C:\AndroidDevelopment\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
            - C:\AndroidDevelopment\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
            - C:\AndroidDevelopment\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
            - C:\AndroidDevelopment\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
            - C:\AndroidDevelopment\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
            - C:\AndroidDevelopment\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\mipsel-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
            - C:\AndroidDevelopment\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
```

The .c file related to the error:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_co_mhmt_myapp_ui_activities_MainActivity_nativeFun(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {
     return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from the other side");
}
```

Comment: You work with AndroidStudio, I believe. Which version? How does your **build.gradle** files look? Maybe you should simply reinstall Android NDK. Note that r11 has been released few hours ago.

Comment: I actually just saw that new release and updated right after I posted this question. I downloaded it thru AndroidStudio and my problem is solved :) I think I had this problem in the first place because I have had downloaded and unzipped the ndk manually instead of thru studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as others stated, related to the NDK installation. Possibly because I had downloaded and extracted the NDK manually. Doing so through Android Studio solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It happens with NDK installations, especially on Windows. In most cases, simple reinstall (preferably - automatic via Android Studio upgrade) solves the problem. Note that the new release 11 has been released recently.